# scala.xml.parsing.ConstructingParser splitting text content

Tags: xml, scala

I am using ConstructingParser to parse XML data into scala.xml.Node. I have noticed that on an XML fragment like

<foo>bar &lt; baz</foo>

The root Elem does not have one single Text child containg "bar < baz" but instead has three separate Text child nodes, one containing "bar ", one containing "<" and one containing " baz". This breaks the subsequent processing of the document. I can merge the Text elements myself, of course, but I was curious if there is a way to make ConstructingParser do this for me.

Gr. Silvio

Answer (score 0):

Scala is not one of mine yet, but I'm pretty sure the answer is "no". There is absolutely no guarantee that the text content of an element will emerge after parsing as a single text node. In this case, there's text, an entity reference, and more text, so it's perhaps not so surprising that the result is three text nodes, but there's no guarantee anyway.